# Helper method to Raise an exception a good idea?

Tags: c++, exception

Is there any reason having a helper method to create and throw an exception is a bad idea? In normal coding terms it would seem sensible but it does mean your stack trace will be a bit more convoluted which is my only concern.

I'm specifically working on C++ here but if you want to cover other languages for comparison/edification go ahead!

Comment: it is possibly more a matter of personal taste. I for my part use a macro to throw that is adding file and line number to my own exception type, something that would be useless if done within a function.